# TypeScript ts(2322) error even after `instanceof` check

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a function that returns a new instance of a type which is selected based on the type of the function's argument.

Here's the code:

```
class A {}
class A1 extends A {}
class A2 extends A {}

class B<TypeA extends A>
{
    a: TypeA;
    constructor(a: TypeA)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
class B1 extends B<A1> {}
class B2 extends B<A2> {}

function createB<TypeA extends A>(a: TypeA): B<TypeA>
{
    if (a instanceof A1)
    {
        const a1: A1 = a;  // OK
        return new B1(a1); // Error - ts(2322): 'A1' is assignable
                           // to the constraint of type 'TypeA',
                           // but 'TypeA' could be instantiated
                           // with a different subtype of constraint 'A'
    }
    else if (a instanceof A2)
    {
        const a2: A2 = a;  // OK
        return new B2(a2); // Error - ts(2322): 'A2' is assignable
                           // to the constraint of type 'TypeA',
                           // but 'TypeA' could be instantiated
                           // with a different subtype of constraint 'A'
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Error();
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-MFwvGYvJkuIMrlXgVSsKKrVFM12t1I31JLJXNgJoigwtVsGro83j+jzD31+Vmsb1NKCQQA)

TypeScript compiler says that "*'TypeA' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A'*" but the `a instanceof A1` check makes sure that it was instantiated with the `A1` type and not with some other subtype of `A`. Is this a limitation of TypeScript or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If later one creates a subtype `A1B` of `A1`, an instance of `A1B` will also be an instance of `A1`:

```
class A1B extends A1 {}
const a1b = new A1B()
console.log(a1b instanceof A1); // true
```

And if one calls `createB(a1b)`, given the return type of `createB`, we expect the result to be a `B<A1B>`, whereas your implementation would return a `B1` (i.e. `B<A1>`).

```
const result = createB(a1b);
//    ^? B<A1B>
```

That is what the error message means.

---

In your case, you could be more restrictive to what your function can output, e.g. using [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) instead of generics:

```
function createB2(a: A1): B1;
function createB2(a: A2): B2;
function createB2(a: A1|A2): B<A1|A2> {
    if (a instanceof A1) {
        const a1: A1 = a;
        return new B1(a1); // Okay
    }
    else if (a instanceof A2) {
        const a2: A2 = a;
        return new B2(a2); // Okay
    }
    else {
        throw new Error();
    }
}

const result2 = createB2(a1b);
//    ^? B1
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8BQpI1gRmgUwA8AXPAOwBMtEV1wo4AmfYsyuatWzaAIQB4AKgE8ADnniESFLAD5UCVNCXQwALmjCxsANyLlwAPakIRAE4BXYEQOmAFGo2jxASkR7lyogAsAlhAB0YNAAvCq6HmhoGPQ8uJKsMPw4MhxcMUzx0rx8sAwpSJzRWNg8zFJsOKmGxkQq2ABGIdCkeADucCW2zuhGEAYgeP4gBgDm9g3QPjVgpMB4BgBmHc7a0AD0a9Bm5ng9NdCmeBDmILWhwIdgJDzj9SuoGx4AegD8qKgL5rNEPkbQF3grnh+JpxGUEnAZPZ1KDYM51CCnLB8u5Jkt7JNprN5kscK4FB4PNUTHV1JVQmBVutNgB5ADSqI8hyI5lMpGabV42HGK2p0AAoqZTDZoABaLYQWwMADMDAY8OgAHIcIrJjBMD4RqQwPUBlsDFsvHh-r0zGAprVFlsnErYYqADSM5SPermWqKu0mk7kaD1Y1TEwzH5An2tHzeFTQcg+BYLPCHUi1Y71Ig2q3Es0WpWwRWotAePAgCD+9FBANEGZzK25fFOpQZlQMMlMClUx70usHPAstkc9o8Bj2eWrR6C4WmMUSqWy+XqZUMVV+FRQTXa3XG6yG40Z0zmxPQK2psS2pEOzsut0nrSqwze33+rHBkih8NeSPR2PxshJ8wptNLHc93dHM81RQtizcQlPC8YV2hadoxxsLpwmUSJ3k+b5fnZAEgQHaFlgRbBdAwqwsP+S5rkHBwawRBhiK+Ui-hwyj8MqAAfRgFSSXAONyFEPBjaAMXLSscWWSCoJNfYwGwMlcFbTtmVZdl4K5HkUKUfNlHAkshLLLEq1xeUJKghswCbRgmkpRTu2UvteCo4dQILItjQJSTvFg+zELse4IlQQpTS7Y5ThbcjARYmS7l0R5lFeVAgA)

Comment: Ah, right, makes sense. Yeah, I considered the approach with function overloads but I have close to a hundred of these types and new types are added quite often. I was not very happy even with `instanceof` checks but the function overload solution requires changes in 3 or 4 places for every new type (overload, argument type / return type, and the `instanceof` check), so I keep this solution as the last resort. I posted a [separate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74119711/parallel-type-hierarchies-in-typescript) question to see if someone knows how can this be solved in a generic way.